# Are email headers case sensitive?

Tags: email, header, case-sensitive, rfc5322

Are email headers case sensitive?

For example, is `Content-Type` different from `Content-type`?

According to [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322), I don't see anything about case sensitivity. However, I'm seeing a problem with creating MIME messages using the PEAR Mail_mime module, and everything is pointing to the fact that our SMTP server uses `Content-type` and `MIME-version` instead of `Content-Type` and `MIME-Version`. I tried using another SMTP server (like GMail), but unfortunately our web servers are firewalled pretty tightly.

Comment: The answer depends on what you're doing; it's not just a matter of 'the rules' that apply equally in all situations. Postel’s Robustness Principle from the early days of the Internet is still an excellent guide: “Be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others”. So if you're receiving emails or parsing email headers, then  'no' they are not case sensitive - but if you're sending emails or tweaking email headers, then 'yes' they are case sensitive. -- Also note that for very old standards (email was first specified by RFC 822 in 1982), common usage trumps 'the rules'.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

RFC 5322 does actually specify this, but it is very indirect.

[Section 1.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-1.2.2) says:

> This specification uses the Augmented
> Backus-Naur Form (ABNF) [RFC5234]
> notation for the formal definitions of
> the syntax of messages.

In turn, [Section 2.3 of RFC 5234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234#section-2.3) says:

> NOTE:
>
> ABNF strings are case insensitive and the character set for
> these strings is US-ASCII.

So when RFC 5322 specifies a [production rule like this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.2):

> from            =   "From:" mailbox-list CRLF

It is implicit that the "From:" is not case-sensitive.

[update]

As for Content-Type and MIME-Version, they are specified by the MIME spec ([RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-2)).  That in turn refers to the BNF described by the original [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-2.1), which (luckily) also makes it clear that these literal strings are case-insensitive.

Bottom line: According to the spec, Email headers are not case-sensitive, so it sounds like your mail server is buggy.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It definitely helped. As a side note, doing more testing, we've determined it's Thunderbird that was the issue. Every other mail client respected the alternative text properly, but Thunderbird chokes.