# set message id sending email with Play 2! plugin

Tags: email, playframework-2.0, jakarta-mail

I am using `"com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.2.0"`. The email i receive has the header "Message-Id". I tried setting header with mail.addHeader("Message-ID", "") and mail.addHeader("Message-Id", s"") but they all fail to override or show up. How do you set the message id?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#msgid

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. I saw it earlier. One problem is the message id is shown as "Message-Id" rather than "Message-ID". When I tried to see if other headers show up such as mail.addHeader("foo", "123"), "foo" does not show up. ?:(

Comment: @kfer38 : What you send as a header is strictly determined by your email service provider. Often custom headers like 'foo' in this case is rejected by them. I think this is exactly what is happening in this case

Comment: @kfer38 : Also see this for your case sensitive problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143549/are-email-headers-case-sensitive?rq=1